# how to understand experiment performance for partition databse

Tags: database, performance, partition, throughput

I am studying the paper *Fast Distributed Transactions
for Partitioned Database Systems*
and I found this paragraph that I did not understand.
What is the difference between `node /machine /partition`
and the meaning of dist warehouse?

[image: Figure 4]

> Figure 4 shows total and per-machine throughput (TPC-C New Order
>   transactions executed per second) as a function of the number of
>   Calvin nodes, each of which stores a database partition containing 10
>   TPC-C warehouses. To fully investigate Calvin’s handling of
>   distributed transactions, multi-warehouse New Order transactions
>   (about 10% of total New Order transactions) always access a second
>   warehouse that is not on the same machine as the first. Because each
>   partition contains 10 warehouses and New Order updates one of 10
>   “districts” for some warehouse, at most 100 New Order transactions can
>   be executing concurrently at any machine (since there are no more than
>   100 unique districts per partition,